# Mongoose cached dbConnect in NextJS showing issue

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongoose-schema

Am using Mongoose for connecting to my db in MongoDB Atlas, in my NextJS app.

Here's the stripped down relevant piece of code:

**dbConnect.js** :

```
/**
 *      MongoDB Connection
 * 
 *  */
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

if (! process.env.MONGODB_URL) {
  throw new Error(
    'Please define the MONGODB_URL environment variable inside .env.local'
  )
}

/**
 * Global is used here to maintain a cached connection across hot reloads
 * in development. This prevents connections growing exponentially
 * during API Route usage.
 */
let cached = global.mongoose

if (!cached) {
  cached = global.mongoose = { conn: null, promise: null }
}

async function dbConnect() {
  if (cached.conn) {
    return cached.conn
  }

  if (!cached.promise) {
    const opts = {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      bufferCommands: false,
    //   bufferMaxEntries: 0,
    //   useFindAndModify: false,
    //   useCreateIndex: true,
    }

    cached.promise = mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, opts).then((mongoose) => {
      return mongoose
    })
  }
  cached.conn = await cached.promise
  return cached.conn
}

export default dbConnect
```

---

This is how I defined the User Model:

**/models/User.js** :

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({

    name: {
        type: String,
        // required: [true, "Name is mandatory"]
    },      

    email: {
        type: String,
    },    

});

// mongoose.models = {}; 

var User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);  

export default User;
```

---

And I have defined custom helper functions to make it easier. So basically these functions will return the results from the database.

**/functions/user_funcs.js** :

```
import User from '../models/User'
import Book from '../models/Book'

//-- get all Users
const getAllUsers = async () => {
    try{
        //-- get the details
        let users = await User.find({})
            .collation({locale: "en" })     //-- for case insensitive sorting
            .select('name email')           
            .sort('name')
            .exec()

        if( users.length > 0 ){
            //-- format the data
            let users_formatted = users.map( p => {
                p = p.toObject()
            
                //-- convert to strings    
                p._id = p._id.toString()               
        
                return p
            } )

            return users_formatted
        }
                         
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log( e )        
    }

    return []   
}


//-- get Books of User
const getBooksOfUser = async (user_id) => {
    try{
        //-- get the details
        let books = await Book.find({})            
            .select('name')
            .where( 'author' ).equals( user_id )
            .sort('name')
            .exec()

        if( books.length > 0 ){
            //-- format the data
            let books_formatted = books.map( p => {
                p = p.toObject()
            
                //-- convert to strings    
                p._id = p._id.toString()               
        
                return p
            } )

            return books_formatted
        }
                         
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log( e )        
    }

    return []   
}

export {
    getBooksOfUser,
    getAllUsers
}
```

---

**/pages/users.js** :

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import Image from 'next/image'    

import Footer from "../components/common/Footer";
import Header from "../components/common/Header";

import styles from '../styles/Users.module.css'

import dbConnect from '../lib/dbConnect';

import { getAllUsers } from '../functions/user_funcs';


export default function Users({ users_data }){


    return (
        <>
            <Header />


            <section className={styles.users_list}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">

                        { users_data.map( (item, i) => (
                            <div className="col-md-3" key={ item._id }>
                                                                
                                { item.name }

                            </div>
                        ) ) }
                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
            

            <Footer />
        </>
    )
}



export async function getStaticProps(context) {    

    //-- db connection
    await dbConnect()
    
    //-- get all users
    const users_data = await getAllUsers()

    return {
        props: { 
            users_data ,               
        }, 
        revalidate: 100
    }
}
```

---

The problem is, when I access the `http://localhost:3000/users` page, it throws the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'User')

The error highlights the following line in **/models/User.js** :

```
var User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest changing

```js
var User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

to

```js
module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", User)
```